# How does compiler combine an executable project using generic parameterized types from another class library project?

Tags: c#

Assume I have a class library project name **Utilities.dll** as follows:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static T Min<T>(T[] data) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T min = data[0];
        foreach (T x in data)
        {
            if (x.CompareTo(min) < 0)
                min = x;
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Then I create a new console app project **Tester.exe** referencing Utilities.dll as follows

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] data = { 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 0, -1, 10 };

        Console.WriteLine(Utilities.Min<int>(data));
    }
}
```

I want to know how the compiler does its job behind the scene. Can anybody know the rough idea about it?

Note that: Assume I have no access to the source code of Utilities.dll when using it on Tester.exe project. Only Utilities.dll is provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET (and unlike things like C++), it is the **runtime** that provides generics. The IL is structured to retain all the generic information (contrasting to Java, which uses type erasure).

In fact, you can create a new `Type` **on the fly** (via `TypeBuilder`), and use reflecton:

```
Type someCrazyNewType = InventType(...); // not shown
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(someCrazyNewType);
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

OT, but re your specific example, I actually recommend a change:

```
var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
foreach (T x in data)
{
    if (comparer.Compare(x, min) < 0)
        min = x;
}
```

This will work even if `x` is null, and supports "lifted" comparisons (against `Nullable<T>`). You can also then remove the generic constraint.

But if we look at your *original* function, the IL is:

```
.method public hidebysig static !!T Min<([mscorlib]System.IComparable`1<!!T>) T>(!!T[] data) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] !!T min,
        [1] !!T x,
        [2] !!T[] CS$6$0000,
        [3] int32 CS$7$0001)
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0002: ldelem.any !!T
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: ldarg.0 
    L_0009: stloc.2 
    L_000a: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000b: stloc.3 
    L_000c: br.s L_002d
    L_000e: ldloc.2 
    L_000f: ldloc.3 
    L_0010: ldelem.any !!T
    L_0015: stloc.1 
    L_0016: ldloca.s x
    L_0018: ldloc.0 
    L_0019: constrained !!T
    L_001f: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.IComparable`1<!!T>::CompareTo(!0)
    L_0024: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0025: bge.s L_0029
    L_0027: ldloc.1 
    L_0028: stloc.0 
    L_0029: ldloc.3 
    L_002a: ldc.i4.1 
    L_002b: add 
    L_002c: stloc.3 
    L_002d: ldloc.3 
    L_002e: ldloc.2 
    L_002f: ldlen 
    L_0030: conv.i4 
    L_0031: blt.s L_000e
    L_0033: ldloc.0 
    L_0034: ret 
}
```

You can see the `T` (for generics) is there, in full. The JIT (in most CLI implementations, not all) is responsible for figuring out what is necessary; typically all reference-type implementations **share** an implementation (since all references look the same under the hood), but each value-type implementation gets a separate JIT (as they have different memory layouts).

Comment: +1 - I tell people, you know a method looks like this: `Foo(put something here at runtime)`. Generics are similar: `new MyFoo<put something here at runtime>()`.

Comment: btw, `constrained` is some clever IL magic that allows you to call a virtual method on a type without having to know whether it is value-type (and needs boxing) or reference-type (so doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

The DLL contains all the necessary information. It is called metadata, and includes the list of types defined in the assembly, the list of methods, properties, etc. Even the fact that the types or methods are generic.

Note that this is independent of the source code itself, and independent of the source language (i.e. metadata generated from VB.NET, C#, Ada.Net, etc. are the same).